# Do you know an annotation like @NonNull for `return` values?

Tags: nullpointerexception, return-value, lombok

There are two examples below for checking or catching Null return values at the source, rather than down-stream.  I came across the perfect use-case today while pasting-in null check boiler plate into delegate functions (it is do nothing code and necessary).

Question:

- Is there something else/library/annotation to achieve this
- And aviding writing custom code to reinvent so many wheels?

Ideally I wanted to use Lombok's `@NonNull` construct to check the return of a function, e.g.:

```
  @NonNull private String isNullReturnValueCaught(){
  }
```

Lamentably this use case has been rejected by Lombok:

- [#907 -- **Enforce `@NonNull` on method return and locals**](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/907)

As well as my other alternative, checking the local variable.

```
  private String isNullReturnValueCaught(){

      @NonNull String rslt;

      rslt = null;

      return rslt;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).  It's existed [in Guava since at least version 10](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html), and Java 7 formalized the API around it.

The pattern with `Optional` is that you're always returning an instance of it, and the overall philosophy is simple:

- You are okay with returning an empty `Optional` because you can fall back to a default value, or
- You are explicitly ***not*** okay with returning an empty `Optional` and you agree that your application should [violently blow up](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) if the value is not there.

Be forewarned:  **`Optional` is not a replacement for null-checks.**  They're only intended to make your code easier to maintain and easier to deal with when you would normally know *exactly* what you have to do when you get a null value.

Comment: Optional is the opposite of what's needed.  In English, it is more like "must return mandatory non-null value".

Comment: @will: Using `@Optional` *does* guarantee you're returning a non-null value. The pattern then becomes such that you extract the value from it if it exists.

Comment: +1, OP wants the behaviour of `@NonNull` but in the return statement. `@NonNull` throws a `NullPointerException` for a `null` argument. This answer provides a link to `orElseThrow`. If you were to throw a `NullPointerException` from `orElseThrow`, unless I'm missing something, provides exactly what's requested.